# Javascript/jQuery function arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

Newbie jQuery / Javascript question here

I see functions written in the following fashion:

```
some_function = function(event) {

}
```

My question is: What is meant by that `event` argument? Is it optional? What if I want to have two additional parameters, X and Y, what would the signature look like? When I call the function now, I can just call it like `some_function();` and it works fine (which leads me to believe that it's optional). However, how will that change when I have two additional arguments like X and Y? Can I just call it like `some_function(myX, myY)` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how the function is called. More code/context, please.

Comment: looks like event handler.

Comment: Are functions and event handlers not the same structure? Isn't the only different the context that they are called in?

Comment: Event handlers are functions, however depending on how they are bound, they may or may not have additional arguments. arguments are always optional when defining a function.

Comment: Yes, it is optional. The values of the `event` parameter depend on the event listened to. You can see what's in it by using `function(event) { console.log(event); }`

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to instantiate a function in JavaScript. They both look the same, but their meanings aren't quite the same.

What you've posted is a function instantiation as part of an **expression** in the language. In that form, the syntax is

> **function** *name* **(** *p1*, *p2*, ... **)** **{** *body* **}**

The "name" and the parameters are optional; the keyword `function` and the parentheses are required. (There are some obscure issues with using a name in this case, in some browsers; it's getting to be less of a problem.)

The effect of that is to create a new function object.  The reference to the object participates in the expression just like any other value (well, like any other reference to an object).  Because it's a function, the reference can also be used to call the function and cause its code ("body") to execute, just like you'd expect. (It wouldn't be much of a function if you couldn't!)

The other way a function can be instantiated is with a function declaration statement, which looks, surprisingly, *exactly the same* (except that "name" is required).  The difference involves where exactly in your code the keyword `function` appears:

- If the keyword `function` is the first thing in a new statement, then you've got a **function declaration** and the "name" is required.  The statement is *not* an **expression statement** in this case, and the only thing the statement does is instantiate the function and bind a reference to the function to "name" more or less as if "name" were a local variable (or global if in the global scope).
- If the keyword `function` appears anywhere else in an expression (either an expression statement, or an expression buried inside some other context, like the top of a `for` or `while` loop statement), then it's a function instantiation expression.

Now, regardless of how a function is "born", once you've got a reference to the function you can call it and pass as many parameters as you like.

---

I don't know personally how the trend started, or whether it's even something that should be considered a trend, but it's fairly common to see local functions instantiated with code like this (and like what you posted):

```
var some_function = function( arg1, arg2 ) {
  /* some code */
};
```

That's an example of a function instantiation in an expression. The net effect is that the symbol "some_function" is bound to the newly-created function.  There are slight nitpicky differences, however, between the way that name is bound to the function from the (almost) equivalent function declaration:

```
function some_function( arg1, arg2 ) {
  /* some code */
};
```

One simple reason that the second way (function declaration statement) is a little better is that the name of the function will show up in stack traces. Of course, one could achieve that with the redundant-looking:

```
var some_function = function some_function( arg1, arg2 ) {
  /* some function */
};
```

I don't really know why you'd want to do that, but it'd work, except in [some naughty environments](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/).

Comment: So is there anything "wrong" with declaring normal functions as expressions rather than as you have posted it? E.g. add = function(a,b) { return a+b; } vs function add(a,b) { return a+b; }

Comment: @Ricky I extended my answer a little.  It's not really *wrong*, but personally I prefer function declaration statements to be a little better, mostly for the debugging advantage. It's probably safe to consider it a matter of stylistic preference.

Answer (score 1):

That code snippet is a little vague, however I can answer, in general, your questions.

The `event` argument, in the code you provided, is just what that function will use to reference the first parameter that is passed to the function from whatever-other code calls it. For example, if you had code that called your `some_function` function, and passed it a string `"hello world!"`, the call would look something like:

```
obj.some_function("hello world!")
```

Inside of the `some_function` function, the variable `event` would contain `"hello world!"`. Also, you could change your `some_function` signature to be: `some_function(blah)` and it would be all the same, you would just use `blah` to reference the parameter instead of `event`. The variable name you choose for parameters is entirely up to you, though you want to make sure you don't use language-reserved names (like `in`, `for`, `continue`, `break`, etc)

Technically all parameters are optional for a JavaScript function, unless the internal code of the function enforces the parameters (i.e. it may return or throw an error if a parameter is missing.

@Pointy answered the other point I was going to make...that the code you provided is defining that function as an expression. I use that syntax when I'm creating a function that is an attribute of an object (which is why my above code has `obj.` at the beginning.